# Inserting a squared random variable into a stochastic differential equation

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to teach myself stochastic processes and I'm going through Kurt Jacobs' [Stochastic Processes for physicists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521765420) and am having difficulty following the math for calculating the second derivative of an example of a stochastic differential equation following Ito's rule of $(dW)^{2}=dt$.

In the following differential equation, where $dW$ is an increment of a Wiener process and $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are positive constants.

$dx=-\gamma x dt\, + \, \beta xdW$

To calculate the second moment, you start by calculating the differential for $x^2$. The solution is given as

$d(x^2)=-2\gamma x^{2} dt + 2 \beta x^{2}dW + \beta ^{2} x^{2} dt$

My understanding is that under the chain rule the differential equation $\frac{d}{dt}(x^{2})$ is equal to $2x\frac{dx}{dt}$, so $d(x^{2})= 2x\,dx$. But if I apply this to the equation for $dx$, I get

$d(x^{2})= -2 \gamma x^{2}dt + 2\beta^{2}x^{2}dW$

which is missing the term $\beta^{2}x^{2}dt$.

Where did I go wrong? Is there a rule of Ito's calculus that I'm not following? I know that from Ito's rule $(\beta x dW)^{2} = \beta^{2}x^{2}dt$, but I don't see where it comes into play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to take a second order Taylor expansion in order to appropriately apply the Ito rule.

So you have $$ d(x^2) = 2x dx + dx^2$$ and you get an additional term $$ dx^2 = (-\gamma xdt + \beta x dW)^2 = \beta^2 x^2 dW^2 = \beta^2x^2dt$$

Comment: Thank you for the help!